# Setting checkbox to be checked/unchecked depending on the column result in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datalist

I have got 2 check box[isSold(bit), Offline(bit)] in the datalist , I want to set that check box to be checked or unckecked depending on the database result of that row. For instance if the product is sold , the sold column will be true , therefore the checkbox should be checked. I tried to do acheive the required result by using code below with no success:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlEditCaravans" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Vertical" DataKeyField="makeID" OnEditCommand="edit" 
            OnDeleteCommand="delete" ItemStyle-CssClass="dleditCaravans" 
            onitemcommand="dlEditCaravans_ItemCommand" 
            onitemdatabound="dlEditCaravans_ItemDataBound">

                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="imgeditCaravan">
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="caravanImage" ImageUrl='<%#String.Format("/images/caravans/{0}", Eval("image")) %>' Height="80" Width="80" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="lblmakeCaravan">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMake" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("make") %>' CssClass="lblheader"></asp:Label>

                            <br />

                            <asp:Label ID="imgDesc" runat="server" CssClass="lblDescription" Text='<%#(Eval("description").ToString().Length>350)?Eval("description").ToString().Substring(0,50)+ "....":Eval("description").ToString() + "...." %>'></asp:Label>

                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#"£&nbsp;"+Eval("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="editImage">
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="edit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" ImageUrl="~/images/newsControls/edit.gif" ToolTip="Edit Caravan"/>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="delete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" ImageUrl="~/images/newsControls/delete.gif" ToolTip="Delete Caravan"/>
                           <br /> <br />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAddToFeature" runat="server" Text="Add To Feautured Caravans" CommandName="AddToCaravans" Enabled="false" Width="210" Height="30" ForeColor="#1D91BD" ToolTip="Add Caravan To Feautured Caravans"/><br /><br />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveFeature" runat="server" Text="Remove From Feautured Caravans" CommandName="RemoveToCaravans" Enabled="false" ToolTip="Remove from Featured Caravans" Width="210" Height="30" ForeColor="#1D91BD" />
                            <br /> <br />
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkOffline" Checked='<%#Eval("offline") %>'  /> &nbsp; <label>Set This Caravan in Offline mode</label>
                            </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                            <SeparatorTemplate>
                            <div class="descSeparator"></div>
                            </SeparatorTemplate>

                 </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this should work: `Checked='<%#Eval("offline") %>'`, if it does not work, it must be a different problem.

Alternatively you can do the same in the `ItemDataBound` event. like..

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
 if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
       DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;
       ((CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkOffline")).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["chkOffline"]);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: can i have commandName property for checkbox, coz i need to insert the false value into the database when the client click on the checkbox

Comment: There is CommandName property of checkbox, but what if you can check weather the previous state was checked/unchecked.

Comment: well i will add the autopostback = true , therefore when the client click on the checkbox it should insert false/true value into database den rebind the datalist , is that the right way of doing it

Comment: Perhaps the question should be; how can I assign a commandName to the checkbox at the ItemDataBound (or other) stage??

Comment: There is no CommandName property exist of Checkbox. Then how can you assign that ?

Comment: Thats what I am asking how we can achieve that for checkbox

Comment: But I guess you can use OnCheckedChanged ??

Comment: can you provide me with an example plz

Comment: protected void chkOffline_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dlEditCaravans.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]);
        bool test = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

    }

Comment: d above code is giving error .. coz it cant find definition for item

Comment: There is one way , you can do this , you can put hiddenfield in your item, In the DataList1_ItemCommand event, you can get the datakey value from HiddenField. In this case you have to use DataList ItemCommand event.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, store the value in  instead of the checkbox and then on the ItemDatabound event you can add find the value of the checkbox from the label and assign the value of checked or not to checkbox.